# How to get the Susy +pad mixin to work?

Tags: css, sass, mixins, susy-compass

I want to use `+pad` to add some padding on a `p`. When I try to add the padding by using `+pad` the `p` extends past the place I want the `p` element to stop. Here is a screen shot of what I mean

[image]

You can see the `p` with the yellow background extending past the middle of the 9th column which is where the pictures stop. I would like the `p` to stop there. When I use `+pad` it always extends it. Same thing happens with `+prefix`

Here is my Susy code:

```
@import compass
@import compass/css3
@import compass/layout
@import compass/utilities/lists/bullets
@import susy
@import normalize
@import base
@import media 

/* Susy Settings */

// $total-columns  : 5            
// $column-width   : 4em            
// $gutter-width   : 1em           
// $grid-padding   : $gutter-width

$total-columns  : 4
$column-width   : 60px            
$gutter-width   : 20px           
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width

$container-style: fluid

$tablet : 9
$desktop : 14

// Susy-grid-background override to draw out horizontal lines
=susy-grid-background       
  +grid-background($total-columns, $column-width, $gutter-width, $base-line-height, $gutter-width, $force-fluid: true)          
/* -------------------DESKTOP ----------------------------------*/

+at-breakpoint($desktop)
  #page
    +container
    +susy-grid-background


  header
    +container
    +pull(.3)
    position: fixed
    left: 0
    right: 0
    top: 0
    height: 0
    padding-top: 0
    z-index: 3

    h1.logo
      +span-columns(2)
      font-size: 12px
      // background: green
      +hide-text
      margin-top: 0

      a
        // +span-columns(2)

        svg
          // background: red
          +leader(1)
          float: right
          width: 97px
          height: 38px

    .pagenav
      +span-columns(2)
      +leader(.5)
      clear: both
      // background: rgba(150,200,250,.3)

      li
        margin-bottom: 1em
        float: right
        clear: both
        a
          padding: 5px



  .main
    +span-columns(12 omega)
    // +leader(2)
    z-index: 1
    position: relative
    // background: rgba(1,240,200,.3)

    .image-group-title
      +span-columns(10, 14)
      padding: 1em 0
      +pad(1,0,10)
      +trailer(.5)


    // p
    //   +span-columns(4 omega, 14)

    img 
      +span-columns(10, 14)
      // clear: both

    .img-4-wide
      +span-columns(5, 14)


  .tile
    +isolate-grid(4, 12)
    +fluid-ratio(1/1, columns(4,12))


  #footer
    margin: 0 1em
    // background: pink
    height: 80px
```

Comment: Could you please share both HTML and SASS via http://sassbin.com ? Don't copy your whole project, only the part relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. Unless you use the `border-box` box-sizing model, padding is added to a span width. If you want an outer span of 9, with a prefix of 1, you need to span 8 and add the prefix.
2. Relative padding is based on the parent element width, not the current element, so `span-columns` and `pad` or `prefix` should always be passed the same context argument. Currently, this is wrong:

   ```
   .image-group-title
     +span-columns(10, 14)
     padding: 1em 0
     +pad(1,0,10)
     +trailer(.5)
   ```

   it should be:

   ```
   .image-group-title
     +span-columns(10, 14)
     padding: 1em 0
     +prefix(1, 14)
     +trailer(.5)
   ```

It's not clear in your example what code is applied to the `p` in question, so very hard to know if I'm actually answering the question, but I hope that helps.